# Kubectl -f Abbreviation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am new to Kubectl commands, I met

> kubectl -f -lapp=nginx

As from [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs), and the command --help

> -f, --follow=false: Specify if the logs should be streamed.

I want to confirm, if I use -f like above in command, does that mean:

```
kubectl --follow=true -lapp=nginx
```

I am asking this because documentation said --follow=false is default, so if I use -f, in this case, it means --follow=true, is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will do the same thing for you. `--follow=true` and `-f` both are same.

here is an example of full command to show log with `-f` or `--follow=true`:

```
kubectl --follow=true logs -n $Namespace pod_name -c container_name
```

```
kubectl  logs -n $Namespace pod_name -c container_name -f
```